# How do i pause my code before displaying the label

Tags: python, tkinter

In my code, I am trying to make a loading screen for a frogger game but for some reason I am encountering a problem where I display a picture and then do the `.sleep` function before displaying a label over the top of it however it displays both of them at the same time it just runs the code 1 second after it should, can anyone help?

Here is my code below:

```
from tkinter import *

import tkinter as tk

import time

window = Tk()
window.geometry("1300x899")

LoadingScreen = PhotoImage(file = "FroggerLoad.gif")

Loading = Label(master = window, image = LoadingScreen)

Loading.pack()

Loading.place(x = 65, y = 0)

time.sleep(1)

FroggerDisplay = Label(master = window, font ("ComicSans",100,"bold"),text = "Frogger")
FroggerDisplay.pack()

FroggerDisplay.place(x = 500, y = 300)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're sleeping for one second. Have you tried sleeping for longer than one second?

Comment: Your `sleep()` occurs before `mainloop()`, but nothing will happen with the GUI *before* `mainloop(). You need something like the `after()` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tkinter: how to use after method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method)

Comment: use root.after() method instead of sleep.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `time.sleep(1)` before starting the `window.mainloop()`, the window is created only after 1 second, and the `FroggerDisplay` label will be created at the same time with it. So, you can't use `time.sleep(seconds)` now.
However, you can use `window.after(ms, func)` method, and place into the function all the code between `time.sleep(1)` and `window.mainloop()`. Note, that unlike the `time.sleep(seconds)` you must give the time to `window.after` (the first argument) as **milliseconds**.
Here is the edited code:

```py
from tkinter import *


def create_fd_label():
    frogger_display = Label(root, font=("ComicSans", 100, "bold"), text="Frogger")  # create a label to display
    frogger_display.place(x=500, y=300)  # place the label for frogger display

root = Tk()  # create the root window
root.geometry("1300x899")  # set the root window's size

loading_screen = PhotoImage(file="FroggerLoad.gif")  # create the "Loading" image
loading = Label(root, image=loading_screen)  # create the label with the "Loading" image
loading.place(x=65, y=0)  # place the label for loading screen

root.after(1000, create_fd_label)  # root.after(ms, func)
root.mainloop()  # start the root window's mainloop
```

PS: 1) Why do you use `.pack(...)` and then `.place(...)` methods at the same time - the first one (`.pack(...)` here) will be ignored by Tkinter.
2) It's better to use a `Canvas` widget for creating a game - unlike labels it supports transparency and simpler to use. For example:

```py
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()  # create the root window
root.geometry("1300x899")  # set the root window's size
canv = Canvas(root)  # create the Canvas widget
canv.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES) # and pack it on the screen

loading_screen = PhotoImage(file="FroggerLoad.gif")  # open the "Loading" image
canv.create_image((65, 0), image=loading_screen)  # create it on the Canvas

root.after(1000, lambda: canv.create_text((500, 300),
                                          font=("ComicSans", 100, "bold"),
                                          text="Frogger"))  # root.after(ms, func)
root.mainloop()  # start the root window's mainloop
```

Note: you might need to change coords with `Canvas`.